# javax.validation and composed annoations

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a group of annotations that are always together like so:

```
@Valid
@ValidPropertyA(kind = "Standard")
@ValidPropertyB(kind = "Standard")
@ValidPropertyC(kind = "Standard")
private SomeReusableType type;

@Valid
@ValidPropertyA(kind = "large")
@ValidPropertyB(kind = "large")
@ValidPropertyC(kind = "large")
private SomeReusableType type;
```

I would like to compose these annotations into a single annotation `@ValidReusableType`, but the problem that I have is is how would I push the `kind` into each of the `@ValidProperty's` that are on the `@ValidResuableType` type?

```
@Valid
@ValidReusableType(kind = "standard")
private SomeReusableType type;

@Valid
@ValidReusableType(kind = "large")
private SomeReusableType type;
```

Is there any way to setup the composed annotation to have it so my `ConstraintValidator` still have access to the `kind` they are validating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible: each constraint is totally independent.

We don't inject any context from the composed annotation into the composing annotations validators.

Comment: I figured this was the case. Thanks.